# Sequelize 'where in' automatically add single quotes to the IDs passed for where param

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I want to get all the data from the table using 'where in' function of Seqalzie. But unfortunately, the number array is converted into a string which leads to false results.

Seqalazie code :

```
 mypromise(Requirement_idLists).then((res) => {  
        return res;
    })
    .then(async ids => {
        filteredIds = ids; // number array
        console.log(`Fetching Technologies` + filteredIds);
        return await SelectedTech.findAll({ where: { Requirement_id: [filteredIds] } })
       .then(async data => { 
            return data;
        });
    })
```

seqalize log:

```
 SELECT `Selected_tech_id`, `Requirement_id`, `Project_id`, `User_id`, `Technology`, 
`Technology_experience`, `Technology_level`, `Technology_version`, `Technology_id`, 
 `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `SelectedTechnologiesTbs` AS `SelectedTechnologiesTbs` 
 WHERE `SelectedTechnologiesTbs`.`Requirement_id` IN ('1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16');
```

I want to get rid of single quote in this ('1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16')

Comment: if `filteredIds` is already an array, then there is no need to put it in another array here: `Requirement_id: [filteredIds]`. My guess is that, because you're wrapping it in another array, Sequelize is calling `toString()` on the `filteredIds` variable which is causing this behavior you're trying to avoid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the "ids" is already an array. If it is, the "{ Requirement_id: [filteredIds]}" , should be [{ Requirement_id: filteredIds }].